# Issue using filename having space as argument in NSTASK (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, nstask, pkgbuild

I am trying to pass argument having space in the foldername to `NSTASK`. However, the command is not executed successfully, but when i try to do it manually on commandline, it works fine.

```
  NSMutableString* archive_path=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
     [archive_path appendString:@"/Users/user/desktop/one two/abc.mpkg"];

NSTask* tar_task = [[NSTask alloc]init];
    tar_task.launchPath = @"/usr/sbin/pkgutil";
    tar_task.arguments = @[@"--expand-full", archive_path, next_path];


    tar_task.standardOutput = pipe;
    [tar_task launch];
```

I tried putting all string `archive_path` in double quotes and it did not work, also i tried to use escape character with space still it did not work.

```
archive_path1 = [archive_path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\\ "];
```

Any reason?

Comment: Check your capitalization - the file system is usually case-insensitive, but is also case preserving, so it depends on the utility you are using.

Comment: I am getting the path programmatically anyway. If there is no space in path, it works fine but when there is space it doesnot work at all.

Comment: I got it.  The issue was because of using `NSMutableString`. After replacing it with `NSString`, it worked fine.